# Is it possible to make rails i18n locales fallback to each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, globalization, globalize2

I'm using Rails 3 with Globalize3 0.2.0.beta4

Ideally I need :fr to fallback to :en and vice versa.

There are cases when only a French translation is available and I need to show it even if the locale is :en.

I tried

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = { :fr => :en, :en => :fr }
```

but somewhat unsurprisingly it causes a stack level too deep error.

Answer (score 5):

I'm changing my answer.

To enable fallbacks, add the following to your environment.rb file:

```
 #support for locale fallbacks
 require "i18n/backend/fallbacks"
 I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
```

Then, you can enable circular fallbacks like you were trying to, eg:

```
   config.i18n.fallbacks = {'en' => 'fr', 'fr' => 'en'}
```

In this case, if something is missing in the en locale, it'll check the fr locale, and then the other way around. I don't get any errors running this.

Source: http://batsov.com/articles/2012/09/12/setting-up-fallback-locale-s-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an array of locales they will be set as default fallbacks for all locales.

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en, :fr]
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to set up just two locales to fall back to each other.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I monkey patched Globalize3. Not great as I have to update the patch whenever the site needs a new locale, but hey, it worked.

```
module Globalize

  class << self

    def fallbacks(locale = self.locale)
      case locale
      when :en then [:en, :fr]
      when :fr then [:fr, :en]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have changed to this:

```
Globalize.fallbacks = {:en => [:en, :fr], :fr => [:fr, :en]}
```

Got from the official docs:
https://github.com/globalize/globalize#fallback-locales-to-each-other

Answer (score 0):

In latest i18n gem (0.7.0) I have found it necessary to define fallback locales like this (in `config/application.rb`):

```
# Custom I18n fallbacks
config.after_initialize do
  I18n.fallbacks = I18n::Locale::Fallbacks.new(at: :"de-DE", ch: :"de-DE", gb: :"en-US")
end
```

You also need to set `config.i18n.fallbacks = true` in all `config/environments/*.rb` files.